# addInterceptor(logger) for OkHttpClient

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I have following class in Kotlin to set QueryParam for HttpUrl :

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException

class RequestInterceptor : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val original = chain.request()
        val originalHttpUrl = original.url()

        val url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("api_key", "")
                .build()

        val request = original.newBuilder().url(url).build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

And it need to be initialize as follow :

```
val logger = RequestInterceptor()
```

On the other hand I have following code to set Log level for Interceptor :

```
val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
                Log.d("API", it)
            })
logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
```

At the end I want to set Interceptor as client for OkHttpClient :

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logger)
                    .build()
```

Problem is : How to have both class definition as well as Log level at the same time to `addInterceptor(logger)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple `interceptors` using below code

```
   val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
   client.interceptors().add(RequestInterceptor()) //<--- 1
   val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
                Log.d("API", it)
            })
   logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
   client.interceptors().add(logger) //< --- 2
```